# Rails listener for expired date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, listener

Is there such a thing as a listener in Ruby, or something similar?

For example, how can I check if user date is expired and needed to send an email few days before?

---

Thanks on your time

Comment: Which is it? Rails 3 or Rails 4? In any case, you're probably looking for a background job. Plenty of guidance on how to do it on the Interwebs.

Comment: Hi, actually it is rails 5, but there is no rails 5 tag? Sorry for confusion. Thanks for suggestion, I will read about background jobs.

Comment: Be careful, there are the traditionnal background jobs: you create a "worker" that is executed on a server dedicated to these tasks performed async, and you have the Cron jobs that are triggered at certain times. There are a lot of gems allowing to perform async tasks (like Sidekiq) and also other gems performing Cron jobs. You can check this article for example: http://derekbarber.ca/blog/2015/09/10/scheduling-background-jobs-in-rails-using-sidekiq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are, broadly speaking, two ways to do this:

1. Regularly **poll** for things that are expiring soon, and send emails accordingly. For example, you could use a *cron job* that runs code along the lines of:

   ```
   Model.where(
     'expiration_date < ? AND expiration_date >= ?',
     Time.now + 3.days,
     Time.now
   ).each do |m|
     m.send_reminder_email
   end
   ```

   You may wish to write this code in a `rake` task, so your `cron` job simply triggers it. (You could also refactor the above query logic into a `scope`; e.g. `Model.exires_soon.each {...}`

   [`whenever`](https://github.com/javan/whenever) is a popular library to configure cron jobs via a ruby DSL.
2. **Schedule** future jobs, to be run at a specified time. This could be implemented via a redis-backed library (e.g. [`resque`](https://github.com/resque/resque) or [`sidekiq`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)), or databased-backed (e.g. [`delayed_job`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)). The precise implementation could vary depending on your needs (e.g. can an `expiration_date` ever *change*? How and when should the reminder email be *cancelled*?), but for example perhaps you could do the following:

   ```
   class Model < ApplicationRecord
     after_create :schedule_reminder_email

     def schedule_reminder_email
       ModelReminderWorker.perform_at(expiration_date - 3.days, self)
     end
   end

   class ModelReminderWorker
     include Sidekiq::Worker

     def perform
       # ...
     end
   end
   ```

Your chosen solution should be determined by the specific needs of your application; there is no silver bullet answer to the problem.

For instance:

- How much consideration do you need to make for performance? With `sidekiq` you should be fine, but polling with frequent cron jobs *could* cause issues; to mitigate this, you could think about adding database indexes, or reading from a slave replica DB.
- Are you concerned about sending emails at totally "random" times, e.g. 2am? Individually scheduled jobs *could* take this into consideration, but it would be easier to implement this within a single polling cron job. (Or perhaps this behaviour is precisely what's desired!)
- Think about how best to log errors, handle deployments, control restarts, recover from crashes, and so on... There are a plethora of tools available for all of this, but it's an important thing to get right in a production application.

---

*In general*, my advice would be:

If you're new to this, and/or just want to get something functional up and running quickly, go with option 1 above. But if you're building something that needs to scale within a large system, seriously consider how best to implement option 2.